# Выборка данных по условию (отбор нечисловых значений в DataFrame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Представим, что есть датафрейм:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"price":pd.Series([1, 'между 1,5 и 2,5', 3], 
                    index=['v1', 'v2', 'v3']), 
                   "count": pd.Series([10, 12, 7], 
                    index=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])})
```

В цене есть некорректное, но важное для меня значение, которое мне нужно выловить и подправить. То есть задача - получить строчки, где значение'price' - не числовое.

Я не смог найти разумного решения этой задачи.
В [документации к numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) Есть метод np.isreal.

Однако, вариант:

```
df.loc[(df['price'].applymap(np.isreal))]
```

выдал ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
   df.loc[(df['price'].applymap(np.isreal))]
 File "C:\Users\v.mazeiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
   return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'
```

А вариант

```
df.loc[(np.isreal(df['price']))]
```

Вернул тот же датафрейм.

Понимаю, что ошибка в синтаксисе, но не могу понять хотя бы где искать правильный вариант решения.

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: price  count
v2  1,5 или 2,5     12

Comment: В данном примере - строчку с некорректным значением price

Comment: Мне нужна выборка со строчками, где значение 'price'  не корректное( не числовое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем строки, в которых значение в столбце `price` невозможно преобразовать к числу:

```
In [10]: mask = pd.to_numeric(df["price"], errors="coerce").isna()

In [11]: df[mask]
Out[11]:
              price  count
v2  между 1,5 и 2,5     12
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, оно сработало. Про метод to_numeric прочитал.  Если есть время, скажите, что произошло при обращении df[mask]? Не знал, что так можно - обратиться к фрейму во фрейме...

Comment: Это так называемый “boolean indexing” - выборка по массиву булевых значений (длина булевого массива должна совпадать с длиной фрейма)

Answer (score 0):

Однокурсники предложили решение, используя метод np.isreal, как и планировалось изначально:

`df.loc[(df['price'].map(np.isreal)) == False]`

или совсем уж python-way:

`df.loc[~(df[‘price’].map(np.isreal))]`

Comment: `df.price.map(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str))` - сделает то же, что и ваш код, но немного понятнее по смыслу. `np.isreal()` - предназначена для проверки того, что мнимая часть числа равна нулю. `pd.to_numeric()` - отработает правильно также для чисел представленых строками: `pd.to_numeric(["1.11", "2.22", 3.33, "XXX"], errors="coerce")`